# Firefox: googleads.g.doubleclick.net Basic Authentication Prompt

Tags: headers, advertisements

I have a strange problem with multiple websites showing a Basic Auth popup as pictured below.

I've also listed the request and response headers. Does anyone know how this can be happening, can't find anything online.

Edit: Everything else seems to be working fine, i.e. Chrome, IE etc.
Also all plugins and addons have been disabled.

**Request Headers**

```
GET /pagead/drt/si?pli=1&auth=bgPaNwTbKLNrVSJ3Z5n6UOmtylBX65_IBFeImF-Peks9xCy0XGf_jqXNWnBzDstTq55sbg. HTTP/1.1
Host: googleads.g.doubleclick.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en,en-US;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
```

**Response Headers**

```
HTTP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
p3p: policyref="https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/gcn_p3p_.xml", CP="CURa ADMa DEVa TAIo PSAo PSDo OUR IND UNI PUR INT DEM STA PRE COM NAV OTC NOI DSP COR"
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Google"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
x-content-type-options: nosniff
Date: Wed, 22 Jun 2016 01:48:31 GMT
Server: safe
Content-Length: 1675
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
Set-Cookie: DSID=ADyxukvvurgyDL47wUaLdAHc2F8eBQNN4in7_mifFEOMlKgeygvem34BPkpXIwmgu_A-U0DpqjMMdy-gWSMWEdsgowAzUqPl_XRCNP7ezurN_57i7vh_9NE; expires=Wed, 06-Jul-2016 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.doubleclick.net; HttpOnly
test_cookie=CheckForPermission; expires=Wed, 22-Jun-2016 02:03:31 GMT; path=/; domain=.doubleclick.net
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25"
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

[image]

Comment: no idea, but the same happened to me a few times in the past hours. edit: see [http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/127667/what-should-i-do-about-gmail-ad-asking-me-for-password](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/127667/what-should-i-do-about-gmail-ad-asking-me-for-password)

Comment: Just saw it myself, Linux, Firefox with AdBlockPlus and Privacy Badger.

Comment: I saw this too.  On my tablet, and on my PC.  Once when opening a gmail page, and one other time, just randomly.

Answer (score 0):

I also started getting this authentication prompt on my websites which contain advertisements from Google AdSense. It seems that only some ads cause this prompt to appear.

The issue was fixed by signing out of all of my Google accounts from the main Google site (https://www.google.com/) I am no longer receiving the authentication prompt even after logging back into the accounts.

None of my several hundred active users are reporting the prompt, so I believe the issue was affecting me because my account was signed into Google AdSense.

Comment: I do manage 15-20 google accounts but signing out of all of them has not helped. I'm currently blocking related domains in the hosts file but this also renders these services useless and is a far from ideal solution.